# How can I write a unit test when using Flux blockFirst()

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, spring-webflux, flux

I am trying to write a unit test for this method that utilizes Flux reactor core library, but the code keeps getting stuck at this "blockFirst()" call. I've tried a few workarounds, mostly attempts at mocking an upstream signals but nothing seems to be working.

Source Code:

```
public CompletableFuture<Data> methodCall (Data data) {

    Request request = request.builder().build();
    client.exchangeForFlux(data, request).blockFirst();
    
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(data);
}
```

Unit Test Code:

```
@Test()
void testRun() {

    when(client.exchangeForFlux(any(), any())).thenReturn(flux);

    methodCall(data);
}
```

After being returned a mock value of Flux library when "exchangeForFlux" is called, the code just stops at the blockFirst() call and runs indefinitely. I've attempted a few different things when the "blockFirst()" method is called, but it never ends.

Below is the Flux.blockFirst() method:

```
@Nullable
public final T blockFirst() {
    BlockingFirstSubscriber<T> subscriber = new BlockingFirstSubscriber<>();
    subscribe((Subscriber<T>) subscriber);
    return subscriber.blockingGet();
}
```

It gets stuck on the return subscriber.blockingGet() line, running indefinitely. I cannot mock a return value since the BlockingFirstSubscriber class is private within the Reactor core library.

Comment: why are you blocking in a NON-BLOCKING framework?

Comment: 1: For unit tests, reactor provides a tool for it: `StepVerifier`. It avoids to block yourself. 2. Instead of blocking manually in your `methodCall`, do `myFlux.first().toFuture()`. 3. If your code hangs indefinitely on "blockFirst", maybe the problem lies in your client code/library. What is the library you use as client ?